# Which simple way is there to display a progress bar in most modern browsers?

Tags: php, html, progress-bar

So I have this:

```
<progress max="100" value="50">   <strong>Progress: 50 of 100 done.</strong>         
</progress>
```

In Opera that works fine, in IE it only displays "Progress: 50 of 100 done" without the bar.

Which simple way is there to display a progress bar in most modern browsers? It is being updated only once the page is loaded so no ajax and so on is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Im sure there are many javascript solutions. Try the jQuery UI Progress bar, it should be more reliable in inferior browsers than the HTML5 tags.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to display a progress bar without using the `<progress>` tag is:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: relative; z-index: 2; text-align: center;">Progress: 50/100</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 50%; background-color: blue;"></div>
</div>
```

It's easy enough to animate too, if you wanted, just by changing the text and the `width` style.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use jQuery for this and still make it compatible with old browsers [take a look at this blog post](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/).